# In Java 8, how can I iterate through two arrays at one time?

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream

I'm writing a Java program that gets data from a CSV file. For each row of data, I need to put each data element into a map using the corresponding header as a key. For example, headerRow[7] and dataElements[7] should be a key-value pair in the map.

Below is the code as I would write it traditionally using Java:

```
private Map<String, Double> readLine(String[] headerRow, String[] dataElements) {
    Map<String, Double> headerToDataMap = new HashMap<>(); 
    for (int i=0; i < nextLine.length; i++) {
        headerToDataMap.put(headerRow[i], Double.valueOf(dataElements[i]));
    }
    return headerToDataMap;
}
```

Is there a way that I can write this code using Java 8 streams - keeping in mind that I'm iterating on two arrays at the same time?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no Zip method builtin

Answer (score 9):

The closest thing you can get to this in vanilla Java 8 would probably be

```
 IntStream.range(0, nextLine.length())
    .boxed()
    .collect(toMap(i -> headerRow[i], i -> dataElements[i]));
```

Comment: There is no `headerRow::[]` +1

Comment: @PeterLawrey was also thinking that would be a neat notation.

Comment: Guava 21 will have `Streams.zip`, but I think turning that into a `Map` afterwards won't be any nicer than this.

Comment: Somehow, the OP’s `nextLine.length` has mutated to `nextLine.length()`, but I still have no idea, what `nextLine` is… Besides, your code lacks the `String` to `Double` conversion.

Comment: The boxing free solution: `IntStream.range(0, nextLine.length) .collect(HashMap::new, (m,i) -> m.put(headerRow[i], Double.valueOf(dataElements[i])), Map::putAll);`

Answer (score 1):

You can make something just a little longer using the **BiFunction** interface.

```
private Map<String, Double> readLine(String[] headerRow, String[] dataElements) {
        Map<String, Double> headerToDataMap = new HashMap<>();  
        BiFunction<String,String, KeyValue> toKeyValuePair = (s1,s2) -> new KeyValue(s1,s2);
        IntStream.range(0, nextLine.length)
                .mapToObj(i -> toKeyValuePair.apply(headerRow[i], dataElements[i]) )
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .stream()
                .forEach(kv -> {
                    headerToDataMap.put(kv.getKey(), Double.valueOf(kv.getValue()));
                });
        return headerToDataMap;
    }
```

The KeyValue type is a simple key value instance generator (code below)

```
private class KeyValue {
        String key;
        String value;
        public String getKey() {
            return key;
        }
        public void setKey(String key) {
            this.key = key;
        }
        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
        public KeyValue(String key, String value) {
            super();
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }
        public KeyValue() {
            super();
        }       
    }
```

Comment: That’s a really strangely twisted stream usage. What’s the point of the intermediate `.collect(Collectors.toList()) .stream()` steps? They don’t add anything useful to the operations, only overhead. You can simply remove both. Further, if you know about `collect`, why do you resort to a `forEach` at the end? And why do you create that `BiFunction` first, just to use it in another lambda expression, instead of writing the intended code right in the lambda expression in the `mapToObj` step?

Comment: @Holger thank you for your remarks. I will examine them asap and feedback